# Компилятор для ассемблера

Tags: компилятор, ассемблер

Здравствуйте.
Какой компилятор по вашему мнению наиболее удобный для Assembler`а? 
Например, сейчас использую FlatAssembler, но он глючит, выдает ложные ошибки...

Comment: Для FlatAssembler лучше FlatAssembler (другие с ним не совместимы). А глючит скорее всего не он...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если под винду, то MASM, если под никсы, то лучше начинать с NASM.

Answer (score 2):

Вы вполне можете использовать встроенный ассемблер: это достаточно удобно, потому что редко когда надо сейчас писать крупный код на ассемблере, обычно достаточно небольших вставок. Тогда подойдет обычный компилятор C/C++

- [GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html)
- [Inline Assembler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ks26t93(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Я работал с ассемблеровскими вставками в среде Delphi, но как оказалось позже, там используется некая модификация чистого асма.
По-моему, basm.

Comment: А что есть "чистый асм"?

Answer (score 1):

[gcc](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GCC) либо [g++](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/G++)

Comment: g++  -  не катит, он больше для си и плюсов.

Comment: Мое дело предложить )

Comment: @Егор Соколов, может, вы имели в виду GNU Assembler (GAS)?

Comment: @Asen, g++ - компилятор С++. При чем тут С?

Comment: @Егор Соколов, я просто уточняю =)

Answer (score 1):

А я предлагаю все-таки разобраться что за "ложные ошибки" выдает FASM. Думаю проблема в коде, а не в компиляторе.

Comment: Если программу запуститть один раз, то она выполняется...если этот же код запустить второй раз, то бывает, вылетают ошибки...

Comment: А поподробнее можно?

Answer (score 0):

`Masm` для макро ассемблера - это так, для общего развития.

Answer (score -1):

`Nasm` довольно гибок и им можно компилировать всякие извращения недоступные другим асмам. Я пользовался сначала `tasm` (мертв как ни крути), и `masm` (жирный и неудобный), `fasm` категорически не рекомендую (ибо "плоский" ассемблер, слишком игрушечный), `ld` есть для `linux`, он встроен в систему, с ним возни много, а можно вообще писать без асма и спокойно компилить прямо под проц через дебаггер майкрософт, для этого даже есть спец. ман, так что писать про это не буду.

Comment: >ибо "плоский" ассемблер, слишком игрушечный

В чем заключается "игрушечность"?

Comment: Следуя логике можно добавить, что nasm - сетевой, слишком запутанный :-)